# How does rails decide to render a form with a method of PUT or POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, rest, form-helpers

Rails generates a form partial that can be used on both the page rendered by a get action and a page rendered by a new action. If it is the former the form's method is set to PUT, if the latter the form's action is set to POST.

How does rails decide which method to use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if the object passed to the form is [`persisted?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b081f6b59fb3f15d12043072ad9b331ffd2bc56e/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L64), the form builder knows that you are updating an object and will therefore render a `PUT` action. If it is not persisted, then it knows you are creating a new object and it will use `POST`.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.button %>
<% end %>
```

If `@user` is a new record, `POST` is used and the button label becomes `Create User`, otherwise `PUT` is used and the label becomes `Update User`. There's not much more to it.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using created_at, as I was accessing my model with client-side js, with the @model exposed as a hash by gon. So I was left with only properties to work with.

Comment: In Rails 6, there is a hidden input `_method` with value `patch` for update action.
`<form action="/books/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
`

Answer (score 3):

Forms editing existing resources use `PUT`, forms creating a new resource use `POST`.  As per REST standards described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

From the rails `form_for` helper code:

```
action, method = object.respond_to?(:persisted?) && object.persisted? ? [:edit, :put] : [:new, :post]
```

and `persisted?` for ActiveRecord is declared as:

```
!(new_record? || destroyed?)
```

Comment: My question was how Rails decides which method to set on the form. What is it using to decide?

Comment: Updated, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks. Afraid @hgmnz beat you to the punch though.