# No route matches [POST] upon form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a really frustrating issue. Here's the flow:

I have a model Project and a model Test. Project has many Tests.

In the project's `show` page, I press a button "Add test" with this:

```
<%= link_to "Add test", new_project_test_path, :remote => true %>
```

This calls the `new` method in my `tests_controller`:

```
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @test = Test.new
  end
```

Since it is a remote call, this will call `new.js.erb` afterwards, which has:

```
$("#tests_table").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form', test: @test, project: @project) %>")
```

This displays a form, _form.html.erb, which starts with:

```
<%= form_for([@project, test], :remote => true ) do |f| %>
```

After filling out the form, I hit the submit button ("Create Test"), which calls the `create` method:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @test = @project.tests.create(test_params)
    end
  end
```

Since the form is remote, this will call `create.js.erb` after completion, which has:

```
$("#tests_table").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'test', test: @test, project: @project) %>");
```

This adds the contents of `_test.erb.html`:

```
<%= render "tests/form", test: test, project: @project %>
```

A test row is always in editable state, which is why the _test partial goes on to display the form again.

Now the new row is inserted with the correct values, and the submit button says "Update Test".

**However**, when I hit Update Test on this newly inserted form, it doesn't go through and the Javascript console shows that the POST request failed:

> No route matches [POST]
>   "/projects/5230920870dbf2ba260000e8/tests/5230ae3970dbf2ec30000239"

How can this be? The new test object with that ID exists, and that's 100% fact. I can retrieve it in the rails console. If I refresh the page and then hit Update Test, it goes through. But only when I newly insert the row via Javascript and hit Update Test, it doesn't go through. Do you see anything at all in here that looks shady?

My `routes.rb` has:

```
resources :projects do 
    resources :tests
end
```

Keep in mind that I can do POST requests to that URL and it works upon a full page refresh, but when the object is new and the form is inserted dynamically with Javascript, something shady happens.

Relevant rake routes output:

```
          project_tests GET    /projects/:project_id/tests(.:format)                                              tests#index
                        POST   /projects/:project_id/tests(.:format)                                              tests#create
       new_project_test GET    /projects/:project_id/tests/new(.:format)                                          tests#new
      edit_project_test GET    /projects/:project_id/tests/:id/edit(.:format)                                     tests#edit
           project_test GET    /projects/:project_id/tests/:id(.:format)                                          tests#show
                        PATCH  /projects/:project_id/tests/:id(.:format)                                          tests#update
                        PUT    /projects/:project_id/tests/:id(.:format)                                          tests#update
                        DELETE /projects/:project_id/tests/:id(.:format)                                          tests#destroy
```

## Updated Details

After inspecting the JS console a bit more, I've found the following details.

If I hit "Update Test" on a form that already existed when I entered the page, here's what you see for Form Data:

[image]

That call returns a 200 Success.

If however I hit Update Test on a form that was added dynamically via JS with the steps above, it shows:

[image]

And that one fails with a 404 not found.

Why is the form not using _patch in the second case? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868699/458960) says that if the object is persisted, the form should use PUT, and I have confirmed in my rails console that the object is in fact persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your routes file to make sure it is setup correctly? This is how I setup items like this.

```
resources :projects do
    resources :tests
end
```

Comment: @maq What's the output of `rake routes`?  I don't think has anything to do with whether records exist.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin keep in mind that I can do POST requests to that URL and it works typically upon a page refresh, but when the object is new and the form is inserted dynamically with Javascript, something shady happens.

Comment: @maq See other answer. You don't have route of that form for POST. I assume when you "tested" that URL, you were testing it with GET.

Comment: @maq Saw it. You still don't have a route of that form for POST, only for PATCH. JavaScript is not specifying PATCH, so a POST is being used.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin so why _patch not being specified in one case?

Answer (score 0):

http verb for update would be a PUT. not POST.

this is the autogenerate route for user resource

```
POST   /users(.:format)                                          users#create

PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                      users#update
```

Do rake routes | grep tests and see if there is a route like below

`POST /projects/:project_id/tests/:id`                              tests#update

You wouldn't find it if you are not adding it as a custom route.

To fix this, explicitly specify the method as put in your update form. Or post your form here.

Comment: No it doesn't. `POST   /projects/:project_id/tests(.:format)` is not same as `POST   /projects/:project_id/tests/:id(.:format)`. your error has the url with test`s id in it

Comment: I don't understand. So you're saying my Update Test button is calling POST rather than PUT?

Comment: yes. that's what your error says `No route matches [POST] "/projects/5230920870dbf2ba260000e8/tests/5230ae3970dbf2ec30000239"`

Comment: Here's the thing: if I skip the whole adding a new Test procedure, and go directly into editing an existing Test, and then hit "Update Test", it works fine. My JS console shows that a POST request was successfully made to `projects/5230920870dbf2ba260000e8/tests/5230a8c070dbf2a5da0001df`. So on a normal case, it works fine. But only in my special flow above does something go wrong.