# Rails generate update form with post instead of put

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using **Rails 4**.
I have a `stream` model which has the following routing code in `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :streams, param: :stream_id
end
```

I get the following routes:

```
    admin_streams GET    /admin/streams(.:format)                  admin/streams#index
                  POST   /admin/streams(.:format)                  admin/streams#create
 new_admin_stream GET    /admin/streams/new(.:format)              admin/streams#new
edit_admin_stream GET    /admin/streams/:stream_id/edit(.:format)  admin/streams#edit
     admin_stream GET    /admin/streams/:stream_id(.:format)       admin/streams#show
                  PATCH  /admin/streams/:stream_id(.:format)       admin/streams#update
                  PUT    /admin/streams/:stream_id(.:format)       admin/streams#update
                  DELETE /admin/streams/:stream_id(.:format)       admin/streams#destroy
```

For new stream there is no problem, rails generates the correct form attributes for the `create` method.
My problem is when I try to generate a form for `update`. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868699/1039488), I code of the form is:

```
<%= form_for @stream do |f| %>
    :
    :
  <% f.button %>
<% end %>
```

However, this is what rails generates:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/streams/xxxx" class="edit_stream" id="edit_stream_4" method="post">
```

As you can see, from some reason the method Rails choose is `post` instead of `put`.

I know I can override the method manually, but I find it hard to believe that this is what I need to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

That is totally correct. Take a look at this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

It's just a Rails workaround to the fact that not all browsers support PUT method. So Rails emulates POST method but knows it is really a PUT.

If you better check your form, you'll find a hidden field like this:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`HTML form tag` takes only `get or post` as values for `method` attribute.

See **[Documentation for form tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp#Attributes)**.

In order to support `RESTful` routes other than `GET and POST(already supported by form)` i.e., `PATCH, PUT and DELETE requests`, Rails uses a work around by creating a `hidden input field` in the form which it later tracks down to decide the type of HTTP request.

For eg:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[By default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) the form_for helper uses POST. But the form_for method can detect if the object passed to it has been persisted or not. If it has persisted, then it recognizes that you are doing an edit and specifies a PATCH method on the form.If not it automatically uses POST! I hope this helps!